# Modeling FX option in a negative interest rate environment

Tags: options, fx

I am working on a project and I am trying to evaluate an FX option with EUR/GBP underlying. As the EURIBOR is negative, how can I do the pricing? I know I have to transform the interest rate, to switch to a continous interest rate (so I should apply log).

Please help me on this. Also, if you have codes for Black-Scholes, Vanna-Volga, Heston, I would really appreciate if you could share them with me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be a problem.  You are taking log(1+rate) not log of rate itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! But doesn't this slightly change the Black-Scholes formula?

Comment: @user27622 look at the formula ... no: it does not matter. It would be a problem if the FX spot were negative. Rates can be arbitrary real numbers.